# Python/Scrapy how do i pass all my data at once using meta?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a spider that extract data from  pages it loops through. But i want that data to pass to my other `parse()` so that I can process it. Right now it only sends data in "chunks" and not in a complete dictionary.

```
def parse(self, response):
    #extracting data
    data1 = response.css('.screener-link-primary::text').extract()


    # Finding and grabing next pages
    nextpage = response.css('.screener-pages+ .tab-link')
    grabpage = str(nextpage.css('::attr(href)').extract()).replace("'", '').replace("[", '').replace("]", '')
    page2= 'https://www.page2.com/market-activity/stocks/mtp'
    nexttab = response.css('.screener-pages~ .screener-pages+ .tab-link b::text').extract()[-1]

    #breaks to next page
    if str(nexttab) == "next":
        yield response.follow(grabpage, callback=self.parse)
    else:
        yield scrapy.Request(page2, callback=self.parse2, meta={'data1' : data1})


    def parse2(self, response):
        data1= response.meta.get('data1')
        mylist = []
        for data in data1:
            mylist.append(data)
    
            print(mylist[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what data you want to pass, but [meta param](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) accepts a dict so all the data you want to pass to the next method can be arranged in the dict.

Instead of

```
yield scrapy.Request(page2, callback=self.parse2, meta={'data1' : data1})
```

it could be:

```
    yield scrapy.Request(page2, callback=self.parse2, meta={
        'data1' : data1,
        'nextpage': nextpage,
        'grabpage': grabpage,
        'arbitrarydata': 'some-arbitrary-data',
    })
```

The dict can be almost* whatever you like. And access it as you are already doing:

```
def parse2(self, response):
    data1 = response.meta.get('data1')
    grabpage = response.meta.get('grabpage')
```

**I mentioned "almost" because there are some special keys that are used by Scrapy. [Here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-meta-special-keys) if you want to know more.*

**A suggestion for further endeavors:**

It's recommended to use `cb_kwargs` instead of meta, if you are using Scrapy v1.7+. The use is slightly different. [Docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs)

`cb_kwargs` parameter receives a dict with arbitrary data that will be used **as argument in the callback function**. So you would have to do something like this in your request:

```
        ...
        yield scrapy.Request(page2, callback=self.parse2, cb_kwargs={'data1': data1})
```

For this to work, you also need to change the callback function to receive this parameter. Like this:

```
    def parse2(self, response, data1):
        ...
```